# Adding -D argument to Webl0ogic Startup

Tags: arguments, weblogic

Trying to add -Djaxb.debug=true to my development Weblogic server
I edited setDomainEnv.cmd added

JAVA_OPTIONS=" -Djaxb.debug=true ${JAVA_OPTIONS}

Can't find the setting in the console where the server was started or in the AdminServer.log

Comment: This option will not be visible in the admin console. You can run a `ps -ef | grep weblogic | grep jaxb.debug` to confirm it is present in your server instance.

Comment: You are correct, I was referring to the linux console where Weblogic was started.  It is working now, thanks

Comment: Great, can you accept my answer. Thx a lot.

Comment: I didn't ask why it was visible in the admin console, which is what you answered.  The confusion is possible because I was referring to the linux console where I started the weblogic server.  The linux console using the *.cmd files.  If I was starting managed server using a Admin server your answer would of been more accurate.  I should of been clearer with my question.

Answer (score 0):

This option will not be visible in the admin console. You can run a ps -ef | grep weblogic | grep jaxb.debug to confirm it is present in your server instance.